# Database selection for Read-only and write-once(insert) every growing data not to be modified

Tags: database, cassandra, hbase, janusgraph, scylla

**Scenerio**

I have to use Janusgraph to store data, and i have a use case where i have every growing amount of data that is not needed to be modified ever. it  will be read only and of-course written once(when being added).

Janugraph provides some storage options, which one should i choose in my scenerio among these

- Apache Hbase
- Cassandra
- Scylla DB
- Berkeley DB

**What i have searched and thought**

Since i don't need to modify the data much, i don't care about consistency much i guess so i should go for Availability and Partition-Tolerance, so Cassandra would be good option?

Answer (score 4):

Full Disclosure - I work on the Scylla project.

I agree that, if fault-tolerance and availability are your primary requirements, you should choose Cassandra or Scylla, as they are best-in-class at those requirements. (Scylla is a re-implementation of Cassandra, sharing the same architecture and API, but with different underlying code. [Details here](https://scylladb.com/wp-content/uploads/Scylla_Seven_Design_Principles.pdf))

Given your use case, if you envision storing multiple TB of data, I would recommend Scylla over Cassandra. Cassandra recommends that you store a max of 1 TB per node. Scylla has no such limitations - there are users storing 20+ TB per node. [Whitepaper here](https://scylladb.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-scaling-up-vs-scaling-out.pdf).

There are other advantages of Scylla vs. Cassandra in terms of throughput, tuning, memory management, etc. But this data density would likely be the primary benefit for you.

Comment: `Cassandra recommends that you store a max of 1 TB per node.` - Thats an antique recommendation. 10-20tb isnt a problem with Apache Cassandra, you can probably do more but bootstrapping starts to suffer.

Comment: I tend to disagree. The most recent Datastax conference was touting upcoming "BigNodes" support that would allow for 5 TB per node, with the asterisk that features enabling this are still under development. 
Reference: https://youtu.be/98CdMGOSSqw (Skip to 33:09)
To me, this indicates that smaller nodes are still the norm for Cassandra.